# Cursor in Android not Returning Rows/Data

Tags: android, sqlite, select, return, android-cursor

I'm new at android programming. can you help me fetch rows using cursor.

with this code i can fetch all the rows :

```
public Cursor getAllDataDays() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MYBUDGETWITHDAYS;
    return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    }
```

this is my code for fetching specific rows:

```
public Cursor SelectAllDaysIntParent(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MYBUDGETWITHDAYS +  " WHERE" + KEY_PARENTID + " = " + id;
    return db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

}
```

but it is not displaying any rows.

please help. thank you.

Main_BudgetPlannerListViewAdapter.java

```
package caraga.tripgurufinal.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.budgetplanner.R;

public class Main_BudgetPlannerListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Main_BudgetPlannerListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView planName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlanName);
    TextView planDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlanDate);
    TextView planDays = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_NumberOfDays);
    TextView CreatedDateTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_createdDateTime);

    planDays.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1)))+ " Days");
    planName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
    planDate.setText("Travel Date: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));
    CreatedDateTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybudgetplann_list, parent, false);
    return retView;
}
```

**NOTE: I want a method with `Cursor` in it because my `listview` custom adapter requires cursor.**

Comment: Where is it not displaying any rows. Post the relevant code too

Comment: Do you get any exception? If not, then there are no rows that match your criteria.

Comment: @Ranjith when i try to use the fist code, it displays all the rows successfully. the second rows displays nothing.

Comment: @m0skit0 i dont get any errors. the listview is just empty.

Comment: @AllanDave post the adapter code...if not full the relevant bits

Comment: Then there are no rows that match your criteria. I suggest you get the SQLite DB and test your queries using an SQLite client. I'm assuming the other methods works fine and fills the view since you didn't ask about it.

Comment: @Ranjith i added the adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
planDays.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1)))+ " Days");
planName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));
planDate.setText("Travel Date: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));
CreatedDateTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));
```

to this

```
planDays.setText(cursor.getString(0)+ " Days");
planName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
planDate.setText("Travel Date: " + cursor.getString(2));
CreatedDateTime.setText(cursor.getString(3));
```